# linear combinations of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i would know if there is some specific  relationship between  eigenvalues of  matrices and  eigenvalues of matrix given by  some linear combination from these matrices.for example let us consider following case :

A =

```
 2     1     3
 0     1     4
 5    12    14
```

> > 

```
[E D V]=svd(A)

E =

   -0.1715   -0.4127   -0.8946
   -0.1829   -0.8789    0.4405
   -0.9681    0.2391    0.0753


D =

   19.7277         0         0
         0    2.1456         0
         0         0    1.4884


V =

   -0.2627    0.1726   -0.9493
   -0.6068    0.7354    0.3016
   -0.7502   -0.6553    0.0885
```

for second matrix

B =

```
 0    12    13
10     9    11
20     5     1
```

> > 

```
[E1,D1,V1]=svd(B)

E1 =

   -0.4725   -0.7037   -0.5305
   -0.6285   -0.1529    0.7626
   -0.6178    0.6938   -0.3701


D1 =

   27.2453         0         0
         0   17.1917         0
         0         0    1.7720


V1 =

   -0.6842    0.7182    0.1265
   -0.5291   -0.3694   -0.7639
   -0.5019   -0.5896    0.6328
```

and finally

```
 C=A+B;
>> [E2,D2,V2]=svd(C)

E2 =

   -0.4193   -0.7946   -0.4392
   -0.4765   -0.2191    0.8514
   -0.7727    0.5663   -0.2868


D2 =

   42.5915         0         0
         0   13.1294         0
         0         0    2.5662


V2 =

   -0.5851    0.7903    0.1817
   -0.5483   -0.2204   -0.8067
   -0.5975   -0.5717    0.5623
```

clearly   if i add  first two i will get  greater values on diagonal,then it is on  the third matrix diagonals,so my question is  will  linear combination  of matrices also affect on their eigenvalues?let say

we have some matrices  say $A$ and $B$ so that

$k*A+m*B=c$

does it also creates some sort of linear combinations between their eigenvalues?or does there exist some special matrices,so that   Eigenvalue of matrix given by sum of  two matrix is just sum of their eigenvalues?thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For diagonal matrices as well as matrices that share the same eigenvectors what you claim is true. I am not sure of the necessary condition.

The eigenvalue is the scalar by which the eigenvector is expanded or contracted by the original matrix $A$. If you have two matrices $A$ and $B$, let $\lambda_{1A}$ and  $\lambda_{1B}$ be (one of) their eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors be $v_{A}$ and $v_{B}$.
The eigenvector of $A+B$ may not be the linear combination of $v_{A}$ and $v_{B}$ as $v_{B}$ will be twisted (not just multiplied) by A perhaps having a component along all other eigenvectors; and $v_{A}$ will be similarly twisted by B.

For perhaps a deeper answer beyond my understanding, I found this reference.
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908012